# Why does ASP.net give errors when trying to minify CSS files for common frameworks such as Bootstrap?

Tags: css, asp.net, minify, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

I'm working on an ASP.net web app.  I needed to make some changes to the CSS, but I ended up having to jump thru some hoops because the previous developer who worked on the app had minified all the CSS files in the source repo.

I decided to make things easier for myself in the future by setting up ASP.net bundling and minification.  It turns out that for some reason, ASP.net throws errors when trying to minify CSS for Bootstrap 3.3.5, Kendo UI v2017.2.504 (specifically kendo.common-material.css), and Material Dashboard Pro v1.1.0.  I get the error `Minification Failed.  Returning unminified contents.`

I tried minifying these files with cssminifier.com and they appear to work fine, so I'm at a loss to explain why I get an error when minifying with ASP.net.

Comment: do not alter the original minified file add a custom.css and add there your things

Comment: For minifications you may need to use a plug-in or extension such as WebEssentials